# Parsing words in a string based on font property

Tags: python, excel, vba, fonts, openpyxl

I'm trying to write a basic Python script that receives .xlsx input and outputs json. One of the spreadsheets that I have has been structured in a strange way. That is, within each cell in column C, there is a string that needs to be separated into two columns. The only thing that structures the parts that need to be separated is a difference in their font. So, for example:

```
"this is in Arial this is in Times"
```

The script that I have so far is as follows:

```
# Import Libraries
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from openpyxl.styles import Font
import sys
import json

# Load argv[1] as workbook
wb = load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
ws = wb.active

# Create wordlist
wordList = []

# Loop through rows in worksheet, create if statements for different columns and append Lemmas to wordList.
for entry in ws.iter_rows('A2:C3'):
    newLemma = {"word":[], "definition":[]}
    for col in entry:
        if col.column == 'A':
            newLemma["word"].append(col.value)
        if col.column == 'B':
            newLemma["definition"].append(col.value)
    wordList.append(newLemma)

# create json
json = json.dumps(wordList)

# write to new file
textfile = open('wordlist.json','wb')
textfile.write(json)
textfile.close()
```

Now, what I need is something like the following:

```
if col.column == 'C':
   if col.font.name == "Arial"
      ...append(col.value)
   if col.font.name == "Times"
      ...append(col.value)
```

Unfortunately, `col.font.name` only gives the font assigned to the whole cell, and not to the string inside the cell. So, if the cell is assigned the font Arial, even though half the words are in Times, `col.font.name` will still produce Arial.

If I loop through each word in the cell using `col.value.split(" ")`, and then try to print the font.name, I receive an AttributeError message that 'unicode' object has no attribute 'font'.

Is there a way of doing this with openpyxl or with another Python library? Or, is there a way to separate a column into two columns based on font type using an excel macro? I'm open to any solutions here, as it would be a big pain to have to manually type a dividing character in each cell.

Comment: Can you dump the data from one cell? Perhaps using a binary format?

Comment: I think you should use XLSXWriter for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openpyxl does not support formatting below the level of the cell and there are no plans to do this: it would make client code incredibly fiddly.

However, starting with version 2.3 the library contains the necessary code to do what you want to do, as long as you're prepared to write your own parser.

Look at how formatting is handled in comments or in shared strings for an idea of how to do this. Note, that formatting is handled completely differently within cells or comments. You will have to iterate through the various parts yourself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to go about doing this? I'm facing a similar problem where I'm trying to parse the characters in a cell based on their font colour. So if a given cell has the string "ThisIsAString", then some parts of the string use a blue font while others use a black font. Which characters are coloured what is arbitrary, and I need to split the string accordingly based on colour